# StackOverflow on Recursive Function

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I have the following function which is supposed to yield all coordinates in a cartesian plane I can reach from an origin in n steps:

The origin is 'location' and the number of steps is 'strength' which is an int 1-10. However, I keep getting a stackoverflow error. Every time I call it I then call clear on the ArrayList positions. Thoughts?

Updated code:

```
// Returns all positions reachable in 'strength' steps
    public ArrayList<Int2D> findEscapeSpace(Int2D location, Field f) {
        // Are we still within the given radius?
        if((Math.abs(location.getX() - this.location.getX()) + Math.abs(location.getY() - this.location.getY())) < strength) {
            System.out.println("Starting on " + location);
            // If this position is not contained already, and if it doesn't contain a wall
            if(!positions.contains(location) && f.wallField.getObjectsAtLocation(location) == null) {
                positions.add(location);
                System.out.println("added " + location);
            }

            // Getting neighboring positions
            ArrayList<Int2D> neigh = findNeighPos(location, f);

            for(Int2D pos : neigh) {
                System.out.println("looking into " + pos + " at depth " + (Math.abs(location.getX() - this.location.getX()) + Math.abs(location.getY() - this.location.getY())) + " and strength " + strength);

                if(!positions.contains(pos))
                    findEscapeSpace(pos, f);

            }

        }
        System.out.println(positions.size());
        return positions;

    }
```

Old code

```
public ArrayList<Int2D> positions = new ArrayList<Int2D>();

    // Returns all positions reachable in 'strength' steps
    public ArrayList<Int2D> findEscapeSpace(Int2D location, Field f) {

        // Are we still within the given radius?
        if((Math.abs(location.getX() - this.location.getX()) + Math.abs(location.getY() - this.location.getY())) < strength) {
            // If this position is not contained already, and if it doesn't contain a wall
            if(!positions.contains(location) && f.wallField.getObjectsAtLocation(location) == null)
                positions.add(location);

            // Getting neighboring positions
            ArrayList<Int2D> neigh = findNeighPos(location, f);

            for(Int2D pos : neigh) {

                findEscapeSpace(pos, f);

            }

        }

        return positions;

    }

public ArrayList<Int2D> findNeighPos(Int2D currentP, Field f) {

        ArrayList neighPositions = new ArrayList<Int2D>();

        int cx = currentP.getX();
        int cy = currentP.getY();

        int maxY = f.HEIGHT-1;
        int maxX = f.WIDTH-1;

        // A few checks to make sure we're not going off tack (literally)

        if(cx > 0 && cy < maxY)
            neighPositions.add(new Int2D(cx-1, cy+1));

        if(cy < maxY)
            neighPositions.add(new Int2D(cx, cy+1));

        if(cx < maxX && cy < maxY)
            neighPositions.add(new Int2D(cx+1, cy+1));

        if(cx > 0)
            neighPositions.add(new Int2D(cx-1, cy));

        if(cx < maxX)
            neighPositions.add(new Int2D(cx+1, cy));

        if(cx > 0 && cy > 0)
            neighPositions.add(new Int2D(cx-1, cy-1));

        if(cy > 0)
            neighPositions.add(new Int2D(cx, cy-1));

        if(cx < maxX && cy > 0)
            neighPositions.add(new Int2D(cx+1, cy-1));

        return neighPositions;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recursion does not appear to have a termination condition.  It looks like you may want to pass `strength` as an argument to `findEscapeSpace()`, and when that method recurses for it to pass a value one less than the one passed to it.

Other than that, your algorithm looks fairly inefficient, as it is likely to generate and test many of the reachable cells many times each, and, moreover, it will be comparatively expensive to check whether each one has already been found.  But that's the *next* problem to overcome.

Comment: (Math.abs(location.getX() - this.location.getX()) + Math.abs(location.getY() - this.location.getY())) < strength, shouldn't this 'if' condition always keep it within the searchable space?

Comment: That just ensures that you won't continue recursing from unreachable cells.  As I already observed, your code does nothing to avoid generating and testing the same cells multiple times.  For instance, if you start at (5,5) then it will recurse to (6,6), among others, and from there it will recurse back to (5,5), among others.  This will go on indefinitely.

Comment: To clarify: your program would perform an infinite repetition *similar to* the one I described in my previous comment, but it would not take the precise trajectory I presented as an example.  It would actually move as far as it could to the top left, and go into a repetitive cycle there.

Comment: Hi @John Bollinger, thanks. I have updated the code (as you can see above) to prevent infinite recursions but it still doesn't work as expected. In fact, it doesn't add as many positions as I think it should. Thoughts?

Comment: Well, your distance computation appears to assume that moves can be only horizontal or vertical.  The resulting accessible space will be diamond-shaped, with the x and y coordinate axes parallel to its diagonals (excluding the effects of any borders or obstacles).  If moves can also be diagonal, such that the accessible space should be square with the coordinate axes parallel to its edges, then you should compute the distance as the *maximum* of the x and y differences, not their sum.

Comment: Ok - that is fixed now thanks :) You said my algorithm was inefficient, any idea where I could look for better implementations?

Comment: Your revised code is already better.  The biggest efficiency issue at this point probably revolves around `positions.contains()`.  If `positions` is a `List` then each invocation of `contains()` requires a linear search, for `O(strength^3)` overall.  If your `Int2D` class has suitable `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods then you could improve that to `O(strength^2)` by changing `positions` to a `HashSet`.  Alternatively, you could keep a scoreboard array with which to track which locations have been visited, so that you can test based only on coordinates.